Is it possible to have a decentralized, public, and verifiable (true) random number generator?
I was looking at ramdom.org which generates random numbers using atmospheric noise picked up by radio receivers. However, it is still a centralized service, and there is no way to know if some results are tampered by the owner. (random.org has third-party audit, but that audit can be compromised as well.)
Then I am thinking if there is a way to generate public random numbers in a decentralized manner. Specifically, there will be a protocol/process for the random number generation, and anyone who follows the protocol should be able to get the same random number at a certain point of time.
A rough idea is that the "randomness" should come from some natural/physical process, and it should be observable by anyone or a large group of people. And an algorithm can be defined to translate the analog data to digital numbers.
I am wondering if this is practical, and if there are already available solutions. We can relax some other common requirements of the random generator, i.e., it is fine to be very inefficient (like one number per day).

Some searches I did:

random.org and other hardware based random generator, they are all owned by single entity and other people cannot verify the results. (People can verify the numbers statistically, but there is no way to tell if a certain number is compromised.)
https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-crash-course-on-proof-of-stake-part-iii-67aa720ea08f There are many decentralized random number generator for Blockchain, but they all require the communications and involvements of blockchain parties.
https://drand.love/ drand is very close to what I want, just the generation process is still "owned" by The League of Entropy, and technically it is still comprisable.


Actually, we don't know how random.org does it.  You have to trust their website and their source code is secret.  Plus SSL interception means that people can see your numbers being delivered so can't be used for cryptography.

Exactly why is decentralisation important to you in this context, please?

Does drand provide something in this area that random.com does not?  It's not clear to me what it's bringing to the question.

@PaulUszak there are many applications, blockchain is an example. The current algorithms used in blockchain all requires computation resources and potentially "money" (on chain message), which are not optimal.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks, they are very similar. I wasn't aware of the other quesiton.

I pursued this epic search about 3 years ago and I still don't have an answer for this https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/89540/distributed-random-oracle-with-verifiable-shares from this forum. Although I'm convinced that it works fine.


The "randomness" should come from some natural/physical process, and it should be observable by anyone or a large group of people. And an algorithm can be defined to translate the analog data to digital numbers.

A problem with this is uncertainty in analog measurements. For natural widely observable phenomena, e.g. astrophysical events, different observers will make slightly different observations, and I see no way to reduce to a practically acceptable level the possibility of disagreement about if the next bit should be a 0 or a 1 without communication between observing parties. Such communication can remove disagreement, but at the expense of allowing a collusion of parties to influence the outcome.
This is exactly why we throw dice or coins: it's an artificial phenomenon with low possibility of disagreement on discrete outcomes. We know how to solve the bias problem, e.g. with Von Neumann's de-biasing.
So the only things I can propose are variations around the theme of public lottery. Independently operated webcams around a dice thrower; giant white/black coin thrower on the surface of the moon operated once every full moon.

Stock markets, as in the geohashing algorithm, offer a discrete value that you can pay to influence, but you can't prevent others from playing, which means that low-order digits have high entropy even against rich adversaries.

"A problem with this is uncertainty in analog measurements"
This is true, and I am wondering if there are ways to remove/minimize the uncertainty. The other question suggested the sun spots, and I will need to read more about it.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I would think low order digits are easy to control if you have sufficient money. If you put a very large buy order at $23.34567 and a very large sell order at $23.34568 you can be pretty sure the price is going to stay in between those values. And if too many people are taking you up on your buy/sell offers, you can switch to $24.34567/8 or whatever you think is a better price. Only someone willing to throw the same kind of money at it as you are will be able to dislodge the low order digits.

@JanKanis For one stock, sure. But does this scale to hundreds of stocks? Even if you assume that the market valuation determines the price of stocks except for their lowest-order bit, If you want to restrict the hash to a set of $2^n$ values, you'll have to control the exact price of all the stocks except $n$.

I'd probably not base such a thing on natural processes. Astrophysics probably gives the best results, but we cannot always see the stars and it will likely require specialized equipment. The fact that we live on a globe makes CMB or Solar activity kind'a hard to sync (same for the moon of course, we cannot always observe it). Gravitational waves can be measured globally, but they are infrequent - a few times per month maybe, and it is probably not something that can be measured in a backyard.
To me it would make more sense to choose some widely publicized values that can be mashed together and are hard to manipulate or dispute, for instance hashing a sequence of least significant digits of GPS satellite data, weather stations and/or seismic sources. For best results the data should have a timestamp attached. I thought of stock market prices first, but those are too easy to manipulate, and stock markets are sometimes halted when trading goes haywire.
Blockchain and Trusted Third Parties have already been mentioned in the question.

All in all, we don't have a globally available, natural TRNG. I the end I'm not sure that a TRNG is often the best option, and in this case I don't think it is.

Exactly what "sequence of least significant digits of GPS satellite data" are you proposing to use? Is it some internal data of the GPS satellite network? Or the location output of a particular GPS receiver? In either case, how do we avoid that the authority that administers GPS (and bows to the US government) influence it?

Perhaps you could use a secure combination of GPS, Galileo, Glonass and Beidou

@fgrieu I'll remove that one from the list, I found one source that claimed that detailed info about the GPS satellites was available, but I cannot directly source it.

Stock markets, as in the geohashing algorithm, are not that easy to manipulate. If you have money, you can easily influence the magnitude high-order digits of individual stock prices. But low-order digits are much harder to control. A few hundred bits per weekday seem doable.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' can't you just put out large amounts of limit buy and sell orders around your target stock price? (Of course, that's expensive, especially if someone catches on.)

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I'm not so worried about stock manipulation, especially if you combine them. But sometimes trading is temporarily suspended and that might cause issues.

This is a classic problem in cryptography. The earliest solution is Blum's 1981 protocol for "Coin Flipping by Telephone". Its setup is slightly simpler than what you've described, but for demonstration, it makes a good place to start. It's indeed a "decentralized" protocol, but with only two parties. It guarantees that, if at least one of the parties is behaving honestly, the resulting coin flip will be truly random.
Blum's original scheme was created in the infancy of theoretical cryptography. A slight generalization of the protocol leads the concept of cryptographic commitment schemes. Reading the Wikipedia article on commitment schemes should give you the basics, and they work through the coin flipping protocol in the examples.

I'm missing the public and (publicly?) verifiable parts in this answer.
